# Insert matrix inside another matrix using numpy without overwriting some original values

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, optimization

I need to insert a matrix inside another one using numpy

The matrix i need to insert is like this one:

```
tetraminos = [[0, 1, 0], 
              [1, 1, 1]]
```

While the other matrix is like this:

```
board = numpy.array([
    [6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
])
```

The code i'm actually using this one:

```
board[0:0 + len(tetraminos), 0:0 + len(tetraminos[0])] = tetraminos
```

The problem matrix that i'm getting is this one:

```
wrong_matrix = numpy.array([
        [[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
])
```

while the expected result is:

```
expected_result = numpy.array([
    [6,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
])
```

The error is that, since the matrix contains 0, when i insert it inside the new one i lost the first value in the first row (the number 6), while i wanted to keep it

Full code:

```
import numpy
if __name__ == '__main__':

    board = numpy.array([
        [6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ])

    tetraminos = [[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

    board[0:0 + len(tetraminos), 0:0 + len(tetraminos[0])] = tetraminos
    print(board)

    expected_result = numpy.array([
        [6,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ])

    exit(1)
```

Comment: You should add your expected output.

Comment: Added the expected output and modified the code :-)

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: I see, i'm sorry if the code wasn't really clear. I will create a new minimal example from start and then edit the question

Comment: It's hard to see what changes you are making in that sea of 0s.

Comment: I changed basically all the question, removing all the old code. I made an example way more minimal and easier to understand with expected output and full code of a sample program. I hope this help, i'm sorry if the question was a mess before

Comment: So you want to write the non-zero values?  To `numpy` a 0 is just as much a 'original value' as is 6.  I think you need to use a boolean mask along with the slicing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you always want to put a constant value in there, you can treat your tetramino as a mask and use the `np.putmask` function:

```
>>> board = np.array([[6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
>>> board
array([[6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> tetraminos = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1]]
>>> np.putmask(board[0:len(tetraminos),0:len(tetraminos[0])], tetraminos,1)
>>> board
array([[6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might do it in two steps:

```
tetraminos = np.array([0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1])
temp = board[0:0 + len(tetraminos), 0:0 + len(tetraminos[0])]                                                                                                                                                                        
board[0:0 + tetraminos.shape[0], 0:0 + tetraminos.shape[1]] = np.where(tetraminos == 0, temp, tetraminos)
```

Output:

```
array([[6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant on the `putmask`

```
In [243]: board = np.array([
     ...:     [6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     ...:     [6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
     ...: ])
In [244]: tetraminos = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
     ...:               [1, 1, 1]])
In [245]: aview = board[:tetraminos.shape[0],:tetraminos.shape[1]]
```

Use the `tetraminos` as boolean to selection slots of `aview` to put values:

```
In [246]: aview[tetraminos.astype(bool)]=1
In [247]: board
Out[247]: 
array([[6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

This could be generalized if `tetraminos` has other non-zero values.